# grid_forget or grid_remove doesn't hide all widgets on the canvas

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

This is not the actual code, i have removed many items just to share the complete code to recreate the issue.
Below are the Steps to Recreate the Issue.

1. Check/Uncheck the Enable Profile Image Checkbox.(Enable or Disable works perfectly fine)
2. Click on Settings Button and retry to uncheck the checkbox to hide items from Canvas. This time it just removes the picture but not all the items on canvas. I want everything to disappear when someone unchecks the checkbox.

Issue here is, when setting function is loaded in **init** for the first time it works perfectly fine but if you click on any other button and come back to settings again to hide the canvas items it just hides the image and not the other two items on canvas.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class AppLayout(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,path,BackGround_LeftPane,BackGround_RightPane):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.BackGround_LeftPane            = BackGround_LeftPane
        self.BackGround_RightPane           = BackGround_RightPane

        self.path = path
        self.ProfileImagePath = ''
        #Open Application on Full screen
        self.state('zoomed')
        
        self.masterPane = tk.PanedWindow(self,bd=0,sashwidth =0 )
        self.leftPane   = tk.Frame(self.masterPane,bg = self.BackGround_LeftPane,height = 600,width = 400,relief = 'raised')
        self.masterPane.add(self.leftPane)
        
        self.rightPane   = tk.Frame(self.masterPane,bg = self.BackGround_RightPane)
        self.masterPane.add(self.rightPane)
        
        self.masterPane.pack(fill = 'both',expand = True)
        
        self.isProfileImageEnabled =0
   
        self.AddButtonsToLeftPane()
        
        self.Settings()


    def InfraChecks(self):
   
        self.InfraChecks_Frame = tk.Frame(self.rightPane,bg =self.BackGround_RightPane)
        self.MenuName_Label = tk.Label(self.InfraChecks_Frame,text = 'Infra Checks',relief ='raised',
                                       bg =self.BackGround_RightPane,fg ='white',bd=0,font=("Arial", 15,'bold','underline'))
        self.MenuName_Label.grid(row = 1,column =0,sticky ='wn',padx=20,pady =(10,0))
        self.InfraChecks_Frame.grid(row=0,column =0,sticky ='nsew')
        

        
    def History(self):
     
        self.History_Frame = tk.Frame(self.rightPane,bg =self.BackGround_RightPane)
        self.MenuName_Label = tk.Label(self.History_Frame,text = 'About',relief ='raised',
                                       bg =self.BackGround_RightPane,fg ='white',bd=0,font=("Arial", 15,'bold','underline'))
        self.MenuName_Label.grid(row = 1,column =0,sticky ='wn',padx=20,pady =(10,0))
        self.History_Frame.grid(row=0,column =0,sticky ='nsew')
        
    
    def Settings(self):
        self.isProfileImageOn =tk.IntVar()
        
        def enableProfileImage():
            if self.isProfileImageOn.get()==1:
                try:
                    self.profileImage()
                except:
                    print("Image Update Error")
            else:
                self.canvas.grid_forget()
 
        self.Settings_Frame = tk.Frame(self.rightPane,bg =self.BackGround_RightPane)
        self.MenuName_Label = tk.Label(self.Settings_Frame,text = 'Settings',relief ='raised',
                                       bg =self.BackGround_RightPane,fg ='white',bd=0,font=("Arial", 15,'bold','underline'))
        
        self.SettingBtn1 = tk.Checkbutton(self.Settings_Frame, text='Enable Profile Image',variable=self.isProfileImageOn, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=enableProfileImage)
        
    
        
        if self.isProfileImageEnabled ==1:
            self.profileImage()
            self.SettingBtn1.select()
        else:
            self.SettingBtn1.deselect()
            
        
        self.MenuName_Label.grid(row = 1,column =0,sticky ='wn',padx=20,pady =(10,0))
        self.SettingBtn1.grid(row = 2,column =0)
        self.Settings_Frame.grid(row=0,column =0,sticky ='nsew')
   

    def profileImage(self):
        self.img_path = ('test.png')
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.leftPane, width=200, height=180, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg=self.BackGround_LeftPane)
              
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.img_path).resize((150,150), Image.ANTIALIAS))
        self.image_on_canvas  = self.canvas.create_image(120, 110, image=self.img)
        
        self.canvas.create_oval(30,30,210,180,width =25,outline ='green')
        self.canvas.create_oval(0,0,240,210,width =80,outline='orange')
        self.canvas.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='n')
        
    
    def AddButtonsToLeftPane(self):
        btn4 = tk.Button(self.leftPane, text = 'History        ',command = self.History,bg = self.BackGround_LeftPane,relief ='raised',
                   bd =4,padx =50,pady=10,font ='Arial',fg='white')
    
        btn5 = tk.Button(self.leftPane, text = 'Checks',command = self.InfraChecks,bg =self.BackGround_LeftPane,relief ='raised',
                  bd =4,padx =50,pady=10,font ='Arial',fg='white')
    
        btn6 = tk.Button(self.leftPane, text = 'Settings      ',command = self.Settings,bg =self.BackGround_LeftPane,relief ='raised',
                  bd =4,padx =50,pady=10,font ='Arial',fg='white')

        btn4.grid(row =5,column =0,sticky ='we',ipady=5,pady =(0,10))
        btn5.grid(row =5,column =0,sticky ='we',ipady=5,pady =(0,10))
        btn6.grid(row =6,column =0,sticky ='we',ipady=5)
        self.leftPane.rowconfigure(6, weight=1)

path = str(Path.home())

app = AppLayout(path,'red','green')

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `grid_forget` will only forget items added with grid. It doesn't know anything about objects drawn on the canvas. Are you aware of that?

Comment: You overwrite some of your widgets (e.g.: `self.MenuName_Label` in the methods `.History` and `.Settings`.) with new objects. Thereby, the reference to the original widgets is lost and they can't be removed or changed, anymore. Only define each widget once and don't initiate them anew.

Comment: @MartinWettstein, my apologies I am new to python/tkinter and i do not understand when you say I am overwritting few widgets in other menus. self.MenuName_Label and other widgets I am writing on the rightPane. I have tried by keeping different names of these objects .setting , -History but still the same issue.

Comment: @MartinWettstein After reading your comment multiple times i understood where I was messing up. Every time I hit Setting or any other button it creates a new object for each widget and since the I am keeping the object names same so it overrides it.  To handle the situation I have created self.objectcreated = False variable in __init__ method and will turn it on when object is created to avoid creating the same object again and again. Is there any better way of doing it? Needless to say You have been great help. :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked out. You could also have created all widgets in the beginning and just place and remove them from the grid whenever you want them. Or try to destroy them before creating a new one. But using a global setting also works.

Comment: Understood. Appreciate your help and efforts for sharing your knowledge. :)